# How should I make a function which generate this Vector3 sequence?

Tags: algorithm, math

sorry if this may be too much to ask for but is there a function to generate this sequence below and onwards? They aren't random, however their sequence may be slightly rearranged.

```
Origin
(0, 0, 0);
```

https://i.imgur.com/8k6407q.png

```
Layer 1;
(0, -1, 0);
(-1, 0, 0);
(1, 0, 0);
(0, 0, -1);
(0, 0, 1);
(0, 1, 0);
```

https://i.imgur.com/PmqYM0o.png

```
Layer 2;
(0, -2, 0);
(-1, 0, 1);
(1, 0, 1);
(-1, 0, -1);
(1, 0, -1);
(-2, 0, 0);
(2, 0, 0);
(0, 0, -2);
(0, 0, 2);
(-1, -1, 0);
(1, -1, 0);
(0, -1, -1);
(0, -1, 1);
(-1, 1, 0);
(1, 1, 0);
(0, 1, -1);
(0, 1, 1);
(0, 2, 0);
```

https://i.imgur.com/EVc0ZOW.png
Layer4: https://i.imgur.com/70HyB7E.png

Any programming language is fine with me.

This is for generating a 3D grid layer from origin.

Comment: I don’t see any obvious pattern to the sequence - can you explain what it is or where it comes from or what its purpose is ?

Comment: It's for generating a 3D grid layer starting from origin outwards. I added a 2D example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us *YOUR* code!

Comment: I just added all those values into an array and use them, however I have to manually add them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to generate series of cell coordinates with the same Manhattan distance to origin.

Generate [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of distance D (1,2,3,4...) into three parts (including zero parts). For D=2 partitions are `(0,1,1)` and `(0,0,2)`

Then for every partition generate 2^k distributions of +/- signs between k non-zero items `(0,1,1)=>(0,-1,-1),(0,1,-1),(0,-1,1),(0,1,1)`

Then for every distribution generate all permutations `(0,1,1) => (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0)` etc

---

As simpler variant - generate partitions accounting for items order ([compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))), then distribute signs.

Note - `stars and bars` approach (with hard-coded partition into 3 parts) is very good there.